# Sending messages from synchronous thread in a Python Discord bot

Tags: python, multithreading, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm developing a Discord bot in Python 3.6 using the discord.py library and I've had issues trying to send a message to a specific channel from the threads I create.

Basically, I have some threads monitoring websites and I'd like to call a function (that I'm passing to the threads) that sends a message to one specific channel when I notice a change on the website.

I initially tried calling `client.send_message()` directly without async/await but it didn't work at all, so I wrote the async/await function sending the message (tested it and it works) but again I had problems calling it from the threads, so I ended up passing the bot client to my threads and calling `self.bot_client.loop.create_task(self.sendmsgfunction(msg))`. That works, but it is incredibly slow (takes around 15 seconds to send the message, and it's probably not the correct way of doing it anyway) compared to the time it takes for the bot to answer a message with the usual `@bot.event` function.

I already tried creating an event loop with asyncio then calling the function, but again I ended up with an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: [call_soon_threadsafe?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe)

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev would you mind providing an usage example? I can't figure out how to run the callback I scheduled

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have a similar problem myself.

Comment: @Jachdich I found out it's far easier to just use a webhook for that kind of things

Comment: You can always just send a direct request to the discord API, via a webhook for instance, there doesn't have to be a heavy async libary like discord.py in between.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asyncio.run()` to run an asynchronous function, like this:

```py
import asyncio

async def async_func():
    print("Async function run!")

asyncio.run(async_func())
```

Answer (score 0):

To change someone's nickname on Discord, you can log into your Discord account from your Mac or PC and select the server of your choice which you can find in the left sidebar. From here, in the server member list window on the far right, simply right-click on your username and select the "Edit Server Profile" option. Then enter your new nickname in the text box and click on the 'Save Changes option. To learn more about this topic, you can learn [how to change your nickname on discord](https://appuals.com/change-nickname-discord/) here. You can also use the slash command "/nick" in chat on this server, followed by a nickname of your choice to easily edit and change names.

Answer (score -7):

If you want to send a message to a specific channel, firstly you should get the channel object.

```
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=channel_id_here)
```

Then you can just do

```
await channel.send()
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question. The problem is with the `await` in a synchronous function.